# Copy Formulas and data from worksheet to another workbook without links

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am trying to copy cells from a workbook called old.xlsm and paste them into the workbook that is currently open. With the following code I can copy the data over but it is then linked to the old.xlsm workbook:

```
Workbooks("Old.xlsm").Worksheets("Bookings").Cells.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bookings").Range ("A1")
```

also tried:

```
Workbooks("Old.xlsm").Worksheets("Bookings").Cells.Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookings").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _ 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

It pastes in the data but adds the links like this:

```
=INDEX('H:\01-Work\Flex & Time keeping\[old.xlsm]Flexi Planner'!C:C,$B12)
```

How do I paste into the current workbook without the links ?

I have seen code to break the links in the workbook but this then leaves only values in the cells and not formulas.

TYIA

Comment: does the sheet `Flexi Planner` exist in the target workbook?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, the target WB has the same sheets but are blank and the rest of the code imports it correctly. this is the last sheet i cannot figure out with it being formulas

Comment: try: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookings").Cells.Formula = Workbooks("Old.xlsm").Worksheets("Bookings").Cells.Formula`

Comment: @ScottCraner comes back with out of memory. does that mean i've stored too many variables ?

Comment: Probably, shrink the range to only the used range: `dim rng as Range`:`set rng = Workbooks("Old.xlsm").Worksheets("Bookings").usedrange`: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookings").Range("A1").resize(rng.rows,rng.columns).Formula = rng.formula`

Comment: cheers @ScottCraner. It's setting the range ok but the second part `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookings").Range("A1").resize(rng.rows,rng.columns).Formula = rng.formula` comes up with a "Application-defined or object defined error" which is confusing me as everything is declared.

Comment: Sorry should have been `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookings").Range("A1").resize(rng.rows.count,rng.columns.count).Formula = rng.formula`

Comment: @ScottCraner cheers that worked. add it as an answer so i can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Workbook References When Copying to Another Workbook

```vb
Sub CopyBookings()
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With Workbooks("Old.xlsm").Worksheets("Bookings")
        ' This covers the case when the used range doesn't start with 'A1'.
        Set srg = .Range("A1", _
            .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    End With
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bookings")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    srg.Copy dCell
    
    dws.UsedRange.Replace "'[Old.xlsm]", "'"

End Sub
```

Comment: cheers. that is also a useful function and will use in future.